# Condense Repetitive jQuery statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty green when it comes to javascript, and programming in general. Can someone give me some direction on how to shorten the below code block. I built the front end with consistent naming so I know it can be done, but I'm unsure how.

```
$('#fd_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#fd_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fd_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#fd_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fl_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#fl_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fl_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#fl_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#el_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#el_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#el_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#el_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fm_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#fm_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fm_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#fm_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#gf_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#gf_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#gf_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#gf_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fg_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#fg_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fg_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#fg_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#en_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#en_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#en_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#en_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fmn_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#fmn_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#fmn_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#fmn_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#gfn_button').on('click', function(){
    $('#gfn_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$('#gfn_content #close_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#gfn_content').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

Comment: Simple, use classes !

Comment: I don't think that will work since he is performing `slideToggle` on a different element for many of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `data-toggle` attribute to all elements that should toggle some other element when clicked. This attribute's value should be a reference to the element you want to `fadeToggle()`:

**Markup**:

```
<div data-toggle="#fd_content">Some content</div>
<div data-toggle="#fm_content">Some more content</div>
<div data-toggle="#gfn_content">Even more content</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
  var elementToToggle = $(this).data("toggle");
  $(elementToToggle).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X7v3Y/).

Comment: I like that - basically the Bootstrap approach. You could even simplify further by using the `[data-toggle]` selector instead of the `toggle-control` class.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to depend on your markup - if the markup for all these elements is similar, you might only need a single event handler. But taking the case where all of these things have radically different markup, you could do:

```
var selectors = [
    ['#fd_button', '#fd_content'],
    ['#fd_content #close_btn', '#fd_content'],
    // ... etc
];

selectors.forEach(function(trigger, target) {
    $(trigger).on('click', function(){
        $(target).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    });
});
```